# A Hypothesis Testing Question and Verification

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, inference

> Suppose we have two p.d.f.'s:
>
> 1. $f_0(x)=1,$ if $0\leq x\leq1$, and $f_0(x)=0$ otherwise
> 2. $f_1 (x)=2x$ if $0\leq x\leq1$, and $f_1(x)=0$ otherwise
>
> We want to test the hypotheses regarding the correct p.d.f. of a random variable.
>
> $H_0:f(x)=f_0(x)$
>
> $H_1:f(x)=f_1(x)$
>
> We take ONE random observation from this population, as our sample. Then, perform an appropriate test of hypothesis for which the probability of Type I error, $\alpha$, is less than or equal to $0.1$ i.e. $\alpha\leq0.1$, and the probability of Type II error, $\beta$, is minimum.

To solve this problem, I am using the Neyman-Pearson Lemma. This lemma tells us that the linear combination $\alpha+k\beta$ will be minimized by the test that rejects $H_0$ if $f_1(x)/f_0(x)>1/k$ for some constant $k>0$.

So I get, $2x>1/k$ implying $x>1/2k$ as the condition for rejecting the $H_0$. That is, my critical region comprises all those values of $X$ such that $X>1/2k$.

Now this test minimises $\alpha+k\beta$, and in fact we want minimum $\beta$ too, so it makes sense to conclude that, for this same test, if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are two Type I error probabilities and $\beta_1,\beta_2$ are corresponding two type II error probabilities, $\alpha_1+k\beta_1=\alpha_2+k\beta_2$ implying when $\alpha$ is maximum, for this test, $\beta$ is minimum for this test.

So, assuming this understanding is correct, I try to obtain $k$ such that $P(X>1/2k|H_0$ is true$)=0.1$ i.e. $1/2k=0.9$, so $\beta_{\min}=P(X<1/2k|H_1$ is true$)=0.81$.

Please check if my method of working is correct.

However, I am quite suspicious at this high value of $\beta_{\min}$ which makes me doubt my working, though I couldn't find any flaw. $81$% probability of making a wrong decision is still a high probability, don't you think?

Comment: Did you mean $\alpha\le 0.01$ or $\alpha\le 0.1$? Also, The Neyman-Pearson Lemma tells you that for a given $\alpha$, $\beta$ is minimized by using the likelihood ratio test.

Comment: Your analysis seems fine. Given you have only a single observation and $\alpha=0.1$, $\beta=0.81$ is remarkably *low*. It is that low only because there is a fairly sharp differentiation between $f_0$ and $f_1$: throughout the critical region, $f_1$ is almost twice $f_0$.